# What should the return value of a JSON GET or POST look like?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, json, http

I'm new to JSON and just starting to wrap my head around it's functionality.

I'm trying to see if I can get print some data from some JSON methods. I've been alternating between the first one and the one that is commented out. The ideas is to see if I can get *anything* printing:

```
id newConnection =  [scAPI performMethod:@"GET" onResource:@"me/connections.json" withParameters:nil context:nil userInfo:nil];



//  id newConnection =   [scAPI performMethod:@"POST"
//            onResource:@"connections"
//        withParameters:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
//                        @"facebook_profile", @"service",
//                        @"imc://connection", @"redirect_uri",
//                        @"touch", @"display", //optional, forces services to use the mobile auth page if available
//                        nil]
//               context:nil
//              userInfo:nil];

   NSLog(@"newConnection %@", newConnection);


   NSLog(@"Is of type: %@", [newConnection class]);



   NSDictionary *dict = [newConnection objectFromJSONString];


for (id key in dict) {

    NSLog(@"key: %@, value: %@", key, [dict objectForKey:key]);

}
```

The above code doesn't err and I get logs such as:

[image]

Does this look right? How do I properly use these JSON methods to get a dictionary of values?

---

**EDIT 1**

To be clear I'm using JSONKit :)

Comment: to write the dictionary to log you can simply use `NSLog(@"%@", dict);`. Your dictionary seems to be empty though (or nill), since no "key .. value .." shows in the log

Comment: @babbidi. Exactly. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would personally recommend using the [SBJSON library](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/). Getting a dictionary with it is straightforward.

Get a response back from a connection, and then use the following code (where response is an NSString containing the response from the server):

```
SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
NSArray *returnData = [parser objectWithString:[response stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\\\" withString:@"\\"]];
[parser release];

NSDictionary *returnDict = (NSDictionary *)returnData;
```

This is unrelated, but for examining JSON data, I would also recommend [Online JSON Viewer](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/). You can paste in your JSON strings and view it with a collapsable array structure. Very convenient.

Comment: JSONKit is included with a project that I'm working on so to keep it simple I'm going to try to stick with that. Any ideas if the above makes any sense?

Comment: To put it another way, what should my output value look like? For some reason I don't feel as if the a string of numbers is correct :(

Comment: OK, so your log is saying that newConnection is a string, and the value of the string is that varchar thing? JSON response should look something like this: `{"key": "value", "key2": "value2"}`

Comment: scAPI is an object of the Soundcloud API (which I'm communicating with). Well, my JSON response is the varchar thing which is not correct. What do you think I'm doing wrong?

Comment: OK, from what I gather from the documentation [here](https://github.com/soundcloud/cocoa-api-wrapper/blob/master/Usage.md), newConnection is just a reference to the connection so you can close it later. It is not the actual data being returned from the connection. I imagine that you need to use the Connection Delegate Protocol to get your JSON string. You should restate your question to ask about using the SoundCloud API rather than using JSON.